# Is there a way to install/update drivers to support my new SATA 3.1 SSD?

Tags: drivers, ssd, sata

My laptop is a [Toshiba Satellite L670-1LX](http://icecat.co.uk/p/toshiba/psk3ee-08u007fr/computadoras-port-tiles-L670-1LX-7571455.html), bought in 2011. It originally had a HDD, but a few days ago I bought a Toshiba Q300 SSD drive. I partitioned it (aligning partitions to multiples of 2048 sectors) and cloned the OS (Ubuntu Mate 16.04) from the HDD to the SSD using clonezilla.

The command `hdparm -t /dev/sda` tests sequential read speed. on my Q300 SSD, its output is **253 MB/s** (average value), whereas it [could be near **550 MB/s**](http://www.toshiba.eu/hard-drives/solid-state/ssd-q300/hdts848ezsta/).

- Could it be because my OS doesn't have the drivers installed to properly support my SATA 3.1 controller? As I mentioned, I did not install Ubuntu to the SSD, I just copied the HDD partition.
- Otherwise perhaps it's not a software issue and my motherboard controller can't support SATA3 at all?

I don't understand all of it, but here is the output of some commands I found on various web pages:

`smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep SATA` results in:

```
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
```

`hdparm -iI /dev/sda | grep SATA` results in:

```
Transport: Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
```

`lspci | grep SATA` results in:

```
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _aligned to cylinders_? There are no cylinders on an SSD. You should align partitions at multiples of 1 MiB.

Comment: @AlexP Indeed, you are right. I did not "align to cylinders", but I am pretty sure I did the alignment right. I checked it with `fdisk -lu /dev/sda` where each partition starts at a multiple of 2048. I will edit my question and remove the "cylinder" part.

Comment: The data sheet says that sequential read speed is _up to_ 550 MB/sec; translated from commercialese, that phrase means that Toshiba guarantees that even in the most ideal conditions imaginable there is no way for the speed to exceed 550 MB/sec; it _does not_ mean that the actual speed on actual computers will be anywhere near that number.

Comment: @AlexP Yes 550 is a maximum. I did not expect the actual speed to be less than half that maximum, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your performance test results are *better* than [what CNET got](https://www.cnet.com/products/toshiba-q300-ssd/review/). (In their tests, Toshiba SSD Q300 was measured at 203 MB/sec read, 187 MB/sec combined read/write). The conclusion of the CNET test was that the Q300 was *"slow and expensive"*.

To be fair, [Anandtech measured](http://www.anandtech.com/show/10084/the-toshiba-q300-ssd-review/) much better performance, but complained of low steady-state performance and poor performance consistency. Anyway, the conclusion was similar: *"the Q300 is a low-end drive and is among the slowest SSDs on the market"*.

Comment: Good point. Anandtech found 433 MB/sec for sequential read: I am puzzled by the gap between those test results.